# Counting graphs on 5 vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

> If we have the set A with $\#A=5$, how much graphs can be made over
>   A?

The solution says $2^{5^2}$, that is exactly the same number of binary relations on A. I initially thought that the solution would be: $2^\binom 52$, but i was worng.

Any tip about counting graphs would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably you are counting undirected graphs with no loops (vertices connected to themselves), but the question is considering directed graphs with loops allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, the number of graphs is  $2^{{5 \choose 2}}$ since we are interested in exactly the number of subgraphs of $K_5$, which is the number of subsets of the 10-element edge-set of $K_5$.  But if the answer given is $2^{25}$, then the question meant to ask for the number of *directed* graphs on 5 vertices.  This is the number of subgraphs of the completed directed graph on 5 vertices, which has 25 arcs (if you include self-loops).  If $V$ is the vertex set of the graph, every element of $V \times V$ is an arc.

Answer (score 1):

The number of possible edges is $|E| = 5^2$.  An edge can be present or not, one edge there are two possibilities.  For two edges there are $4$ possibilities, and so on..., so the answer is $2^{|E|}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why "The number of possible edges is $|E| = 5^2$ "?

Comment: The number of possible edges is $n(n-1) /2 = 10$ normally if you don't include loops to-from a single vertex.  But since graphs can have an edge from one vertex to itself there are $n^2$ possible edges.  Count them.  One for each $n$, for each $n$.

Comment: Ok, now i get it.

Comment: No, actually you're right, please uncheck my answer.  There are $n(n-1)/2 + n$ possible edges. But for a directed graph it's probably $n^2$.